# FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.java:1554: error: cannot find symbol

Tags: android, flutter

i have flutter app script which is purchased from code canyon. after compiling it android phone i am getting this error in my phone.

if it is android 33 error then let me know

```
    launching lib/main.dart on RMX2020 in debug mode...
    Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
    Warning: The plugin flutter_local_notifications requires Android SDK version 33.
    For more information about build configuration, see https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
    One or more plugins require a higher Android SDK version.
    Fix this issue by adding the following to /Users/apple/Downloads/stackfood/User app and web/android/app/build.gradle:
    android {
      compileSdkVersion 31
      ...
    }
    
    Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
    Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
    Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
    Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    /Users/apple/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-9.9.1/android/src/main/java/com/dexterous/flutterlocalnotifications/FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.java:1554: error: cannot find symbol
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
                                                        ^
      symbol:   variable TIRAMISU
      location: class VERSION_CODES
    /Users/apple/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-9.9.1/android/src/main/java/com/dexterous/flutterlocalnotifications/FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.java:1555: error: cannot find symbol
          String permission = Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS;
                                                 ^
      symbol:   variable POST_NOTIFICATIONS
      location: class permission
    2 errors
    
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
    
    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':flutter_local_notifications:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
    > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
    
    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
    
    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
    
    BUILD FAILED in 1m 11s
    Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1



    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.S)
    {
      String permission = Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS;
      boolean permissionGranted =
          ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mainActivity, permission)
              == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

      if (!permissionGranted) {
        permissionRequestInProgress = true;
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            mainActivity, new String[] {permission}, NOTIFICATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
      } else {
        this.callback.complete(true);
        permissionRequestInProgress = false;
      }
    }

    else {
      NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(mainActivity);
      this.callback.complete(notificationManager.areNotificationsEnabled());
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

go to the line by clicking from error message .then

Just Comment out

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {---}
```

and remain the else part .
now it will work fine . issue with latest version permission . **Tiramisu** not yet stable

Comment: which part i need comments because  here code written inside it.   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
    {
      String permission = Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS;

Comment: yes but you still can comment it out , and in one part you need to return true . (you can check from clicking error from your debug console)

Comment: i am posting code of that class you can edit it

Comment: i updated the code please check

Comment: i think better solution right now is to downgrade it for now until sdk 33 is stable, how do i downgrade it ?

Answer (score 0):

upgrade this line
android {
compileSdkVersion 33

defaultConfig {

```
    targetSdkVersion 33
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to sdk 33 didn't worked for me because dependency limitations, some of the packages don't support sdk 33 yet, i have set the flutter_local_notifications plugin to the latest version that support sdk 31,
in the file pubspec.yaml
i added this

```
flutter_local_notifications: 9.7.1
```

to the dependencies list